# Initialize tinymce in wp-admin with default wp-editor settings

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I'm creating a metabox which contains an 'add content' button. Everytime you press it, a box with extra content is added. In the already existing blocks on pageload I use the wp_editor function which works correctly.

Now, when I add a block of content with jQuery I want to fire tinymce init on it. I got the following code:

```
                    tinymce.init({
                        selector:'#content_'+count+
                    });
```

This works, it fires tinymce on the selected textarea, but I can't find how I can configure it to be exactly as the standard wp_editor.. How do I have to call it to get it exactly the same as the default editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the default options wordpress uses. They are located in:
`/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`.

Instead of copying that you can more easily just extend the existing tinymce object and tell it to include your textarea with:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, '#content_'+count);
```

Comment: @JeroenBalk Are you sure that tinymce is loaded before your script? (`<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"></script>`)

Comment: Yes I'm sure. This is at the top of the metabox printing function:
wp_enqueue_script( 'tiny_mce' );. Also tinymce.init as stated above did load a tinymce editor, just not the one with the correct settings, and I don't know how to extract the settings from the class-wp-editor.php file, since the settings are formatted in php and not in jQuery.